# Invalid Calendar Items showing in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have several Exchange/Outlook accounts connected to my iPhone.  On one of my calendars, several recurring events from several years ago recently reappeared and will not let me delete them.

When I look in Outlook, the events are not there.

I have attempted to move all of the items out of the affected calendar (via Outlook) into a new one, but the invalid items remain on my iPhone.

When I try to delete or decline the event, it simply returns to the main screen and the item remains.

Is there a way for me to purge these invalid items from my iPhone?

Comment: It's been awhile since I had a similar issue, the resolution was to log into iCloud.com from a regular browser on a computer and delete the event there.

Comment: Hi @Tyson,
I logged into iCloud and none of my calendars are there.  They originate from my Office 365 accounts.

Comment: I Guess that doesn't help.  At the time, my calendar was exchange also, but some feature copied every event to iCloud and in certain circumstances re-curing events would not delete until it was done on iCloud .